# How can a child element alter the appearance of the parent when active?

Tags: css

I have an img element inside of an li element, when the user clicks on the image I want to change the background of the li element.

```
#image:active {
    XXX background-image: url("row_selected.png");
}
```

What do I need to put for the XXX part to reference the parent li?

Thanks

Comment: Not something you can do with just CSS AFAIK.  You need javascript.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector